# Please check your user name and password error message when I am trying to log in andFBChat1.3.0

Tags: performance

I installed andFBChat app on android emulator and when I am traying to log in using my facebook account , it says wrong username and password although they are right

why !!

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure they're right, the app is buggy and we can't help you, Facebook has changed their protocol/accessibility (and the app is out of date/won't work anymore) and we can't help you, or possibly you aren't connected to the internet and you should connect, or the port the app uses is blocked and we can't help you.

Comment: So any one can help me to find source code for android facebook chatting ?

Comment: No, we can't help you with app development-related issues.  But the official Facebook app is in the Market and supports chat, can you not use that?

Comment: I need to code simple one, I don't want to install one from the market

Comment: StackOverflow is the place for development questions.  You'll have to post a specific question about what you're trying to do, however -- "How can I code a Facebook chat app for Android?" won't work.